# Javascript: Sent ajax request to login api -- where to save token?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've sent credentials to a login API and in the success response, there's a bunch of user data and a token.  How can I save this so the the user doesn't have to login each time?   I am assuming I should store the token and user data from the response in a cookie and I can load that information on the page if the cookie exists?

Comment: Did you tried to google, how to save data on browser? Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be advised, that this is not a homework production site. It is expected to tell what you have already tried, and in how far it didn't work, then ask a detailed question. Just dumping your questionnaire and asking others to fill it out for you is considered rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage. localStorage is designed to store data in browser and it remains for each website.

Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) to find out more.

And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is the Mozilla Docs.

Also consider encrypting the data your are storing in the localStorage.

Have fun :)